# Socialite Provider: Driver [strava] not supported

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-socialite, strava

I have followed the instructions for implementing the Strava Socialite provider on a fresh Laravel 5.5. install: http://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/strava/

The only change I've made is to wrap the array key in a string in App/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php as below as it complained about unknown constant otherwise:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\Event' => [
        'App\Listeners\EventListener',
    ],
    '\SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled' => [
        'SocialiteProviders\Strava\StravaExtendSocialite@handle'
    ]
];
```

The error I get is:

```
InvalidArgumentException
Driver [strava] not supported.
```

Is there a known issue with 5.5 or is it obvious I've missed a step?

Comment: Although my answer will resolve your question, "it complained about unknown constant" is a little concerning — what version of PHP are you using? This may be indicative of further problems to come.

Comment: Thanks, your answer worked perfectly @sam I am using 7.2. I did find it odd as all examples for other providers are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're providing the class as a string then you should do so without the global namespace reference (`\`):

```
protected $listen = [
    'SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled' => [
        'SocialiteProviders\Strava\StravaExtendSocialite@handle',
    ],
];
```